# How to create the attribute table for a raster that was produced by the Slope Tool (ArcGIS10)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, spatial-analyst, slope

I use the Slope Tool  (Spatial Analyst Tool – Surface) of ArcGIS10 by ASTER GDEM (that was exported to UTM projection). 
The program produce new raster (with slope value), but the resulting raster doesn’t have the attribute table (it has it in inactive form). But it’s possible to create a map from this raster by slope value, it’s possible to represent each pixel of the secondary raster in its unique value, but impossible to open the attribute table.

The same problem has the Aspect Tool (Spatial Analyst Tool – Surface), maybe some others.
Also I can’t convert this raster to a polygon, because Raster to Polygon Tool doesn’t see it as a raster.

How I can make the attribute table of the resulting raster  active?

Comment: As a floating point raster, it potentially has a unique value at each cell and therefore is not represented with an attribute table. The question really is *why would you want to do this?* There are some good reasons and some really bad ones, so your edits to this question to provide some context and explain your objectives would help you get appropriate answers.

Comment: you can use Reclassification option and the table will be activate.

Comment: It has to do with the attribute of elevation not being an integer. The error message is misleading. I have the same issues all the time. I'm still trying to work out how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I am with @whuber in that you should have a very good reason to do this and not just because you feel like you need an attribute table. Most operations can be accomplished on a floating point raster. Following the advice of a straight conversion to an integer raster, the data is truncated or rounded, and you can introduce serious issues such as contour bias.

That said, you can get to an attribute table and keep precision by multiplying by a constant (eg.. 100) and then coercing to an integer raster.

In ArcGIS 10.2 raster calculator this can be done in one fell swoop.

```
Int( ("slope" * 100) )
```

By using a constant, you can coerce back to a floating point raster by reversing the process.

```
Float( ("slope" / 100) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can either convert the grid to an Integer Grid, or use the 'Build Raster Attribute Table' tool in ArcToolbox.

- ArcToolbox Window
- Data Management Tools> Raster> Raster Properties> Build Raster Attribute Table

Comment: The Build Raster Attribute Table doesn't want to do it with this raster (error 000423 : Only single band integer raster dataset is a valid input)

Where I can try to convert it to other GRID format? The Conversion Tools- From Raster  doesn't have it.

Comment: Very strange format of raster. 
Some tools - refuse work with it (don't recognize it as a raster or  give an error).
But Zonal Statisitc tool works (so, I think I can do somthing by dint of it).
Also I can extract the values of this raster to the shp points by Spatial Analyst Tool - Extract Values\Multi Values to Points (it also works).

Answer (score -3):

http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/33239

Here is how to fix this problem